# Heroku dyno doesn't appear

Tags: python, heroku, dyno

I have created a discord bot in python and I'm trying to host it on heroku without much success. I didn't receive any errors when I deployed it, but the dyno I need won't show up. I have a Procfile with this in it:

```
worker: python bot.py
```

but for some reason no dyno appears after I deploy the build.

If you need more context, or if this isn't enough info, please tell me to elaborate

Comment: Could you add the key parts of your code? The question doesn't have much information, so it's hard to help you with the problem.

Comment: My code works fine from the terminal, so I know that isn't the issue. And I have managed to solve the problem by now too! Turns out the problem I was having was because I pushed a folder full of junk into my git repository on accident. After I deleted it, the dyno showed up!